# Loading Highcharts in an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, highcharts

I'm trying to load a chart (using Highcharts) in an iframe, I load highcharts but the console returns *$(...).highcharts is not a function*

```
$('<iframe id="panel_frame_container" frameborder="0"/>').load(function(){
            $('#panel_frame_container').contents().find('body').append("<div id='panel_chart_container'></div>").end()
                                                  .find('body').append('<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"><\/script>').end()
                                                  .find('body').append('<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"><\/script>').end()
                                                  .find('body').append('<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"><\/script>').end()
                                                  .find('body').append('<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"><\/script>').end()
                                                  .find('body').append("<script type='text/javascript'>$(document).ready(function(){console.log('loaded');$('#panel_chart_container').highcharts("+data2+");});<\/script>");
        }).appendTo($(".panel-body"));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s82v657e/

My goal is to let the user set is own datas (data2) so I choose an iframe to lock him out of my main window since he can use functions in highcharts, so I'll probably add some sandbox tag in my iframe when the first part will work.

Comment: You need to be sure you are including Highcharts within the page that you are loading in iframe. The iframe is a separate window that does not automatically have access to everything that its parent has.  **In the case of your fiddle, you need to make sure you are including Highcharts at all - I do not see it in your list of resources**.

Comment: Thanks but Highcharts is loaded in the iframe with jQuery l.64, 65 and 66.

Comment: How about using Highcharts constructors? One is `new Highcharts.Chart(options, callback)`, and second one is `Highcharts.chart(container, options, callback)`. It looks like jQuery is not loaded yet, so constructor isn't attached to `$` namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should not inject yours scripts with javascript like that.
Instead create a dynamic page like iframe.php with all your content it will be much easier.

Iframes have restricted rights and the way you load yours scripts doesn't guarantee you they will be done one after another

Quick example for the iframe.php content, just pass the data_id inside the iframe URL:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_GET['data_id']))
$data = getGraphics( $_GET['data_id']);
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="panel_chart_container"></div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#panel_chart_container').highcharts(<?=$data;?>);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I ended up using something else than an iframe but your solution works perfeclty ! Thanks very much !

Comment: What did you use @Nico_ ?

Comment: I get back to the iframe solution by @mymyoux, mine wasn't safe to cover every cases I needed (I used a div and I changed the html code with javascript, but since I wanted the user to be able to enter datas, an iframe is better to prevent security issue else a user could have broken my page).